# Swift 3 double rounding func

Tags: swift, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I'm having floating point precision issues writing a 'number prettifier' in Swift. I have this code:

```
func prettifyNumber(number:Int) -> String {
    let thousands = Double(number)/1000.0;
    var prettyNumber = String(format: "%.1fk", thousands)
    return prettyNumber 
}
```

My desired behaviour is:

5000 -> "5.0k"

9999 -> "9.9k"

50300 -> "50.3k"

99999 -> "99.9k"

etc...

However, if I pass in 999999, I get:

999999 -> "1000.0k"

with `thousands == 999.99900000000002`

I know I can do some string manipulation to fake the right answer, but I'd like to implement this cleanly. Any suggestions?

Many thanks!

Comment: FYI - you might be interested in the `ByteCountFormatter` class.

Comment: BTW - `99999` is not `99.9k`. It really is `100.0k`.

Comment: These numbers aren't a measure of bytes/kb/mb/gb etc.

Comment: They don't need to be a measure of anything specific to use `ByteCountFormatter`. If you want to convert a number by dividing by 1000 and showing the `k` suffix, it should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use number formatter setting minimum and maximum fraction digits to 1 and set roundingMode to down:

```
extension Formatter {
    static let kNumber: NumberFormatter = {
       let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
        formatter.roundingMode = .down
        return formatter
    }()
}

extension Int {
    var kFormatted: String {
        return (Formatter.kNumber.string(for: Double(self).divided(by: 1000) ) ?? "") + "k"
    }
}
```

---

```
5000.kFormatted     // "5.0k"
9999.kFormatted    // "9.9k"
50300.kFormatted   // "50.3k"
99999.kFormatted  // "99.9k"
```

Comment: Thank you - this is just superb. I really appreciate you taking the time to lay out a complete example.